Dataframe write failing in Databricks with error 'ValueError: can not serialize object larger than 2G'
I am trying to process and parse the data from xml file to delta table in azure databricks using python script.
We receive files in xml format and we parse it as structured format using dataframes.
But while writing the dataframe to the table it is throwing the serialization error and failing.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 13 in stage 35.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 13.3 in stage 35.0 (TID 901) (10.139.64.13 executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'ValueError: can not serialize object larger than 2G'.
Below is the cluster configuration I am using for the activity.
Driver: Standard_D64s_v3 · Workers: Standard_D64s_v3 · 1-8 workers · DBR: 13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)
I tried with multiple cluster configuration and still getting the same error.
Do I need to configure any additional settings in the code ?
Any Idea how to resolve the serialization issues ?
Thanks in Advance!

Spark uses byte arrays throughout the code, a good summary of this can be found here: https://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/05/10/SparkPartitions/
in short byte arrays have a 32 bit signed integer max: 2g
This also affects maximum row size, shuffling and a bunch of other tasks.  In this case your error stems from here:
def _write_with_length(self, obj, stream):
        serialized = self.dumps(obj)
        if serialized is None:
            raise ValueError("serialized value should not be None")
        if len(serialized) > (1 << 31):
            raise ValueError("can not serialize object larger than 2G")
        write_int(len(serialized), stream)
        if self._only_write_strings:
            stream.write(str(serialized))
        else:
            stream.write(serialized)

There are a number of parameters in the SparkPartitions blog that may help, if you are storing the xml with each row that could also contribute if they are particularly large, if so try removing that field for a test write.
